# Windows overusing RAM and task manager percentage does not match the values

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager, memory-usage

I've been trying to fix my RAM overusage by the system, because it has about 80 to 90 percent at idle and starts crashing after an hour of using just Skype and three Chrome tabs simultaneously while having Discord and Steam in the background. The thing I recently noticed is that in the task manager the ***percentage*** of RAM shown as used by a process multiplied by the total RAM amount (even excluding swap) is about twice the RAM ***value*** it shows for that same process. I have 4GB physical memory and task manager shows that, for example, Chrome uses about 350MB, and when i switch the mode to percentage it says about 20% which is 4096MB times 20% = 819MB, which is twice as much. What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please go to the processes tab of your task manager and double click on the memory header so that it sorts the applications according to the highest memory usage, and share the screenshot so that we can see if there are certain processes that might be hogging your RAM. You can share the link in the comments section or you can post in the question, by simply dragging and dropping it, a link would be created on it’s own.

Comment: You can try another process, it is not alwasy doubled. This should not be a problem, your memory won't be overused, it is just we don't know the exact sum up method used in Task Manager. BTW 4G is not enough if you open some extra program, 8G is baseline.

Comment: Do you have memory paging disabled? When you crash what is the stop code?

Comment: 1. Do you have a 32-bit OS? 2. The memory shown as allocated to Chrome is only for the overall process, click the reveal arrow to the left & add all the page vales to that for a more accurate figure.